# Corda JVM process usage high via rpc-client-observation-pool-0

Tags: corda

In Corda 4.1, I started up a few nodes. Then, I put a few 1000 txns through them. As expected cpu spiked during this time. However, an hour later, the java process is still using 100% of available CPU. Nothing additional is being output to the logs.

When I do dashboard there seems to be two jvm processes called **rpc-client-observation-pool-0** chewing up 50% of the cpu, even when the rpc client that was running against it has quit. Not gonna lie - the machine hasn't got the most ram allocated to it.

I can see in the logs this message A hot observable returned from an RPC was never subscribed to. This wastes server-side resources because it was queueing observations for retrieval. It is being closed now, but please adjust your code to call .notUsed() on the observable to close it explicitly. but I would have hoped that after an hour+ all of the hot observables would have been closed (as per the error) .

Any pointers as to what can I do to tell the node to explicitly close these or find out what has caused this continuous CPU usage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set -Dnet.corda.client.rpc.trackRpcCallSites=true on the JVM,
command line and you will get a stack trace with the warning explaining where is leak is coming from.

If you are calling an RPC method which returns an Observable and If you don’t want an observable then subscribe then unsubscribe immediately to clear the client-side buffers and to stop the server from streaming.